# Using CountIf under a header VBA

Tags: excel, excel-2007, autofill, countif, vba

I am using a countif function to check if I need to use autofill, but I encountered a problem where my raw data had two entries but these were merged together in my destination sheet. I can't use a form of unique count if as when these cases occur, they will not have the same reference anywhere, but are linked. Is there a way to countif on my destination sheet under the header?

```
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(wksdata.Range("D:D"), "MAN002") > 1 Then 
wksdestination.Range("B6:R6").AutoFill Destination:=wksdestination.Range("B6:R" & Lastrow)
End If
```

This caused the macro to break as it was trying to autofill to the bottom of the sheet, a count of cells from A6 down would be ideal, A5 has a title in it, A3 has the word "Month" and A1 and A2 are merged to form A1:L1 and A2:L2 respectively.

Comment: If I can get it to only count if Range("C:C") = "MRI" then that might give the required result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realised I was doing something complicated when there was a really simple solution. Check if A7 has data.

```
 If wksdestination.Range("A7") <> "" Then
```

*facepalm*